# How to show emoji encoded in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, emoji

I'm using AngularJS and sending request to get the emoji. This works perfectly:

```php
$emoji = "aa \xF0\x9F\x98\x81";
echo json_encode(array($emoji));
```

It gives me the real emoji. But when I retrieve that from database, I get the pure text, not emoji:

```php
$emoji = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM emoji")->result_array();
$emoji = $emoji[0]["emj_text"];
echo json_encode(array($emoji));
```

How do I get the emoji instead of just text?

Comment: What do you mean pure text? Do you mean you get the unicode? Such as U+1F601 for your example of \xF0\x9F\x98\x81?

Comment: @CrhistianRamirez No, I get the exact plain text. I mean this: `aa \xF0\x9F\x98\x81`